# How can I get Carrot2 to save Basic Query?

Tags: carrot2

In the Search widget of Carrot2 (3.12.0.0), you can select the disk icon and do a "Save As...". This saves all the attributes of the Search widget (in our case we are using Solr, so it's all the Solr fields), but it doesn't save the Basic Query field (the only required field in the widget). In the image below, all the yellow highlighted fields are saved, but not the "Query (required)" field that is circled.

I've downloaded the source from Git (http://project.carrot2.org/source-code.html), but I don't see how I can update the code to save this value or to even understand why it isn't saved by default.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the report, I've filed an [issue](http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1134) for us to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the code. Or rather some special condition (why it's there, I can't tell). See this bug for the follow-up.

http://issues.carrot2.org/browse/CARROT-1135

Comment: Looking at the issue that you referenced, it says that the Fix Version/s is **3.13.0**, but looking at the [main project page](http://project.carrot2.org/), it says that the latest Release is **3.12.0**. I've looked around the site, but I don't see any projection for the new release. _Do you know when we can expect the next release?_

Comment: 3.13.0 hasn't been released yet. I can make a release for you if it's crucial, but you can always just fetch the binary or build it yourself?

Comment: It's not crucial. I'm an "on loan" developer for another group in our company. I'm providing tools for an editorial group that is using Carrot as part of their workflow process. I've been avoiding building it myself because I'm not sure how wide the our user community is and I don't want to deal with distributing the updates to them. I'm hoping to wait for an official release, so I can just point them to the official website and tell them to get the latest code.

Comment: I'll make a bugfix release this weekend, no big deal. Will let you know.

Comment: Done, it's released. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/carrot2/carrot2-core/3.13.0/